# Insert condition in php variable

Tags: php, variables, conditional-statements

I have a string php variable:

```
$string="some text";
```

Depending on condition I need to add a word to text:

```
 $string="some text true"; //if condition true
 $string="some text false"; //if condition false
```

Of course, I can make something like this:

```
if ( a = b) {
$string="some text true";
}
else {
$string="some text false"; 
}
```

but in fact "some text" is a huge variable with a lot of other variables and it's ugly to duplicate so large parts of code.
Also, code logic doesn't allow to do such:

```
if ( a = b ) {   
string .= "true"
}
```

-because variable looks like "some text (true or false)".$var."other long text", so I can't concatenate word to variable, I need to insert it depending on condition...

I want to do something like this:

```
$string="some text".if (a=b){echo 'true'} else {echo 'false'};
```

Of course, it does not work, condition is not allowed after point.

How to correctly insert or concatenate some condition in php variable?

Comment: *"code logic doesn't allow to do such"* - why is that?! Also: the ternary operator `?:`.

Comment: `if ( a = b )` you're making an assignment with that logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the short if form using ternary operator:

```
$string = "some text".((a==b)?"true":"false");
                        ----   ----   -----
                    condition  true   false
```

Comment: Great, it works! Ternary operators are allowed for concatenation.